# spring boot how to specify location of logback.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I'm using spring boot, and I want to put the logback.xml file outside the classpath, so that I can change the content of logback.xml more easy.  I'm using windows 10 and the location of the logback.xml file is :

**C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.37-50099**

I do specify this location in application.yaml like this

```
logging:
  config: "C:/apache-tomcat-9.0.37-50099/logback.xml"
```

But spring doesn't find the location of logback.xml, because no log file is created.
How can I specify the location of the logback.xml file ?

Answer (score 4):

Our configuration uses a different property:

```
-Dlogging.config=file:///your/file/location/logback.xml
```

Hope it helps someone stopping by.

Answer (score 0):

The first hit on "where should logback.xml go" gave me

https://dzone.com/articles/logback-configuration-using-xml

> For Logback configuration through XML, Logback expects a Logback.xml or Logback-test.xml file in the classpath. In a Spring Boot application, you can put the Logback.xml file in the resources folder. If your Logback.xml file is outside the classpath, you need to point to its location using the Logback.configurationFile system property, like this.

> -DLogback.configurationFile=/path/to/Logback.xml

Comment: Can it be a remote http/https url ?

Comment: @bhantol I don't understand fully your question, but if I'm parsing it correctly, you want to know if the config file can be pulled from a url rather than local. Reading through https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html and the javadoc for the service-provider loading facility, I believe that the answer to your question is "definitely not".

Comment: You got it but its unfortunate I can't externalize it into a remote spring config server or a url needing me to bundle or that external file

Comment: Actually, that DZone article suffers from very indisciplined use of capital letters and as a result, the system variable that's given there and that you have given above, is incorrect and *does not work*. The correct property is `logback.configurationFile` (lowercase l) so the full VM argument is `-DlogbackConfigurationFile=/path/to/logback.xml` . Here too, convention is to call the file `logback.xml` with a lowercase "l".